# Modeling a hierarchical security with a graph

Tags: arangodb

I'm trying to create an access control list for my documents. Each document needs to store which groups have CRUD rights, well not create rights on a created document. The rights may be hierarchical in that a document might not have explicit rights, but rather inherit them from the account that owns the document.

For example a user can have lots of recipes. By default the user only allows his group to read the recipes. Think Linux style groups where each user gets their own group. This default is part of the user's profile. Now for 10 recipes the user allows the group "public" to read the recipes. These are explicit designations within the recipe document itself.

Is a graph a good fit here? Should I have a vertex for user and a vertex for recipe with an edge between them called, I don't know, OWNS? In the query I could say, in pseudocode, WHERE recipe.CRUD.readers contains "public" OR recipe's OWNS inbound profile.recipes.CRUD.readers contains "public". Is this doable? Would Arango perform well on this?

I know I could duplicate the default CRUD from the profile down into the recipes. This seems like a) a massive waste of memory, and b) error prone if the system gets out of sync (do transactions work across collections in a cluster?), and c) operationally intensive since ever document has to get scanned and possibly updated.